# setting UIDateFormatter from String in Swift (1.2)

Tags: ios, swift, date, set, uidatepicker

What I want to do, is to retrieve date from string where it's saved, and pass it to UIDatePicker (scrolling date picker element), so here is my piece of code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!   

@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    //converting date to string to show in table cell

    func dateToString (date: NSDate) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    }

    //converting string from table cell to edit date

    func stringToDate (string: NSString) -> NSDate {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
        return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateToString (myDatePicker.date))!
    }

// here we are saving our data picked from text field and date picker UIs

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if saveButton === sender {
            let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
            let date = dateToString (myDatePicker.date) ?? ""
            item = Item (name: name, date: date)
        }
    }

// Here we are retrieving data when press tableCell cell:

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let item = item {
            nameTextField.text = item.name
            myDatePicker.setDate(stringToDate(item.date), animated: true)

            // also need to pass date smhw
        }
    }
```

Saving from UIDatePicker to string in UITableCell - no problem, passing string (UILabel) to UITextField - no problem, but I can not pass string to UIDatePicker.
It's no warnings, build - no problem, launch, but no action happened.
Please suggest the solution on this issue. I am coding swift 1.2.

Comment: Why are you using 1.2? Don't be coding in 1.2. Seriously. Do you realize 4 has just been released? Try to code it in swift 3. You'll get a lot more help which you can use and carry forward.

Comment: I can not afford mac or macbook, that is why I am using VMWare. And because my CPU is AMD, only OS X 10.10.5 can be installed via virtual machine, therefore my only choice is Xcode 6.2 which has swift 1.2. Please, past a solution in swift 3.0 here, I will correct it syntax wise :)

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that   Sorry for my comments. It's just that it's hard to help you if you're on very old software.  And even worse you have to learn a number of things that are now wrong!  You'll have to unlearn a bunch of stuff just to become current. I'll take another look at your question when I'm back at my mac. I should be able to help you. Although I hope someone else does before me -- it'll be a few hours.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding. I am learning basics, and basically Xcode 6 has very similar structure to version 8, at the beginning it's ok, and also I often see some swift 3 code samples too, so I am fomiliar with some changes... though I am really thinking about subscribe for VirtualMac kinda thing to code in actual environment.

Comment: I wish you good luck and will be happy to help when I can. !

Comment: oh, I've resolved this issue by correcting the code in my StringToDate `func stringToDate (string: String) -> NSDate {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
        return dateFormatter.dateFromString(string)!
    }`

Comment: Excellent! Congrats. 

Comment: Thank's! Will keep coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
func stringToDate (string: String) -> NSDate {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"
        return dateFormatter.dateFromString(string)!
    }
```

This works.